# mysql lost connection 50 second doing alter or massive data insertion

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to alter tables with lots of rows but failed with an error message
`Lost connection to MySQL server during query`. It occured exactly 50 seconds after the query execution.

I checked other answers in stackoverflow and modified mysql configuartion variables. I set net_write_timeout to 1 hour, quite enough and much longer than 50 seconds, and also set other every *_timeout things to 1 hour.

But it didn't change. It failed exactly on 50 seconds again. So I changed every variable whose value is 50 including something looks irrelvant to this issue, e.g, 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout'. Now there is no variable whose value is 50, but nothing changed. Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: why dont you split the query into smaller queries

Comment: It's alter query. I can't do it and even if I can solve this problem doing it, I want to know the solution.